# problem when try to predict an hand written digit with keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(input_train, output_train) , (input_test, output_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()



input_train = input_train/255
input_test = input_test/255

input_train = input_train.reshape(60000, 784)
input_test = input_test.reshape(10000, 784)
input_train.shape

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
           tf.keras.layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(784,)),
           tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
           tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'),
                       
])


model.compile( optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(input_train, output_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128)

model.predict(input_test[2])
```

show me this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 784) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 784), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_9_input'), name='dense_9_input', description="created by layer 'dense_9_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 784) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 784), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_9_input'), name='dense_9_input', description="created by layer 'dense_9_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-2d3c56829481> in <module>()
----> 1 model.predict([[input_test[2]]])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1801, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1790, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1783, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1751, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 228, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_3" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense_9" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=(('tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)',),)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

Comment: `input_test[2]` is a 1D array, but you need to supply a 2D array.  `input_test[2:3]` or `input_test[2].reshape(1, -1)` maybe?

Comment: yes right? this worked input_test[2:3], but i don't understand why? why I need to add two D arrays? since output_test[2] is 7 , why input_test[2] doesn't work?

Comment: Keras allows you to predict the result for not just 1 sample, but any number N of samples.  N samples obviously needs a 2D array of shape (N, 784). So even if N=1, Keras wants you to give it an array of shape (1, 784) not (784,)

Comment: so, how can i predict for only one image?

Comment: Use a 2D array with only one row :) `input_test[2:3]` works like you say, but maybe `input_test[2].reshape(1, -1)` makes it clearer what you are doing.

Comment: this doesn't work, and I think there is another way it should work with only one diminution array as well, I have seen videos about it.

Comment: To clarify: `input_test[2:3]` works (per your earlier comment), but `input_test[2].reshape(1, -1)` does not? What is the error message?

Comment: Some other ways to do it, if you prefer any of these: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13461/how-can-i-get-prediction-for-only-one-instance-in-keras